# Dependency Injection in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, angular, dependency-injection, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to map objects in domain and API resources.
If I have a CustomerResource object, for example, and want to map it into Customer (domain object), I have to instantiate it:

```
CreateMap<CustomerResource, Customer>().ConstructUsing(cr => ...)
```

In my case, there is no public Customer-constructor. Only CustomerRepository has a "Create" method to create Customer.

My problem is, how can I retrieve the CustomerRepository object in Mapping (I inherit the Profile class)? Dependency-Inject does't function in this case, since "services.AddAutoMapper()" does not allow DI in constructor (or am I wrong here?).

Thank you in advance!
Xinyu Zhu

Comment: i i thnk if you want to use DI in it you have to pass in the constructor IMapper mapper

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how to pass parameters in IMapper-constructor?

Comment: try this https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dependency-injection